# ASP.NET Core WebApplication IIS Express Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis-express

IIS Express server is not starting and throwing the following error.

> The following error occurred when trying to configure IIS Express for project <project_name>.
> Filename : redirection.config
> Error: cannot read configuration file

I have reinstalled IIS Express server, removed and installed all the packages and even repaired visual studio. But nothing worked.

I removed `.VS` folder, even this didn't worked :-(.

Comment: Not a direct fix to your issue, but if you are only trying to debug you can choose to run your webapp through it's built host without IIS Express, use the drop down on the Start debug button to select the app name, usually below "IIS Express" option

Comment: Yeah, I have done this and it works fine with Project Profile, but I'm not getting why IIS Express is failing. Where are these config files located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the fix, I don't know how my %userprofile% directory has two Documents named folder. Really Strange. I have no idea why there were two folders with exact name "Documents".I copied IISExpress and Mysites folders from Second Documents Folder to First Documents folder, And it worked.

Edit:
Those Documents folders were actually not in same folder there were in

1. `C:\Users\<username>\Documents`
2. `C:\Users\<username>\OneDrive\Documents`